# Stepping on someone elses work

Tags: discussion, support

I have been working on a question on SuperUser for a user who was having issues with VMWare images and player, but now I am very concerned.

> [All VMware software & their installers fail to start, all of sudden, with no error messages & without getting listed in Task Manager](https://superuser.com/questions/384117/all-vmware-softwares-their-installers-fail-to-start-all-of-sudden-with-no-er/385041#385041)

@David states that this was already previously addressed, but question was deleted; and the @user was perturbed about that.

I don't want to step on anyone's toes here, and do work, invest my time, give advise on research that I have done, if someone else has already done this, and the user already rejected the information.

How should i proceed on this?  Should i just ask it be deleted, apologize to @David for basically reiterating what he posted, or just continue to help the user, even though it doesn't sound like it would be a good idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> apologize to @David for basically reiterating what he posted

Sorry but David's [answer](https://superuser.com/a/383908/4377) was nowhere as comprehensive as yours.

His answer was:

> First off I would check the Windows log files in
>   startmenu->systemcontrol->administration->eventlog. I don't know where
>   Windows stores the log files physically. You can also try the Process
>   Monitor: http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896645.

Yours focuses on probable causes,  basic *and* advanced troubleshooting. I don't see any overlap or "stepping over" and see absolutely no reason why you should delete your answer or even apologize for that matter.

Comment: Could you please link to the original topic you're quoting from?

Comment: @DanielBeck done

Comment: Thanks Sathya and @Daniel Beck; Sometimes I'm not fully sure what to do on these sites just yet lol.  I think the user stopped reading anyway, given he hasn't responded to the last comment i posted about a clean install, so eh, on to other questions.

Comment: @zackrspv you're always welcome to drop by [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) & talk and hang out with us

Answer (score 6):

You significantly improved upon David's answer without even knowing it existed. So there's no reason at all for you to apologize or delete your answer.

---

Whether you're wary of user regarding the possibility of your effort being wasted on this question is for you to decide. A bounty has been offered, so the topic cannot be deleted anymore AFAIK, and half the bounty will be awarded automatically anyway.

My assumption is that the user didn't want a negative score associated with his question. The original question was a bit worse than the first revision of the new one.